# How to do a scale open animation in Flutter?

Tags: animation, dart, flutter

I'm trying to do this animation in flutter :

https://material.io/guidelines/motion/choreography.html#choreography-creation

[image]

My problem is that I have absolutely no idea how to do that.
As far as I know, widgets in flutter don't know their position nor the position or other widgets at all.
And you can't access `context.size` inside the build method.

I tried to use Hero animation to do it. Or ScaleTransition. But it's definitely not working.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`showMenu`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/showMenu.html) to dynamically show a popup menu at a given location. Consider using [`PopupMenuButton`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/PopupMenuButton-class.html), which is an `IconButton` that automatically shows a menu when it is tapped. There's an [example](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/examples/flutter_gallery/lib/demo/material/menu_demo.dart) in the Gallery. If `showMenu` doesn't do what you want, you can copy the code in [popup_menu.dart](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/d1b222bef6c567476308943c5848d6eae9759c1e/packages/flutter/lib/src/material/popup_menu.dart#L587) and customize it to make your own version. It uses `CustomSingleChildLayout` and `PopupRoute`.

If you just want to absolutely position a `Material` or `Card` on top of other elements, you can give it some elevation and use a `Positioned` within a `Stack`. You can use an `AnimatedSize` to adjust the element's size with a `Curve`. This won't interact with the back button on Android automatically, so if you want that, you may have to use [`addLocalHistoryEntry`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/LocalHistoryRoute/addLocalHistoryEntry.html) or `PopupRoute`.

Comment: But I don't want to display a menu.  showMenu won't work with this : https://storage.googleapis.com/material-design/publish/material_v_11/assets/0B14F_FSUCc01MDBDd3JsRV9kZWM/Continuity_02_SingleShared_v6-remapped.webm

Comment: Updated my answer with some other ideas.

Answer (score 1):

If I understand you correct - you want to show square widget, and animation is not suitable at most because widget doesn't know its size.
In this case you can try MediaQuery.of(context).size.width - it returns width of your screen, so you can use it for calculating widgets size